# ACR Reactive BluetoothLE Plugin Invalid State when starting server

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am building an iOS app with Xamarin and MvvmCross the required the use of Bluetooth LE. I am trying to use this plugin:

https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle

Here is my code:

```
var server = CrossBleAdapter.Current.CreateGattServer();
await server.Start(new AdvertisementData()); // throws exception
```

It throws an exception when trying to start the server:

> {System.ArgumentException: Invalid State - Unknown   at
>   Plugin.BluetoothLE.Server.GattServer.Start
>   (Plugin.BluetoothLE.Server.AdvertisementData adData) [0x0005f] in
>   <4281c4bd57f24525b20baae1afdf610b>:0

Apparently this plugin is easy to use so I must be missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of placing the code in my Core project, I placed it inside the iOS project itself, in a `ViewDidAppear` function, and placed a global variable in my `UIViewController` class:

`private IGattServer server = CrossBleAdapter.Current.CreateGattServer();`

I think you need to access the adapter with the appropriate thread, or at the appropriate time (after other initialization), hence why it was crashing before. I couldn't find an appropriate place to put this in my Core project, so I'm not sure if I have to put this code in each platform. Anyhow here's a solution for anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That Exception indicates that the hardware is in invalid or initializing state and can be seen here: https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle/blob/master/Plugin.BluetoothLE.Apple.Shared/Server/GattServer.cs#L74

```
if (this.manager.State != CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn)
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid State - " + this.manager.State);
```

I believe this is a bug in the code as it does not wait for the delegate to signal that the State has changed.

Comment: I think I was accessing it at the wrong time or thread, blocking important initialization that needed to be done first.